# Is there any human verification mechanism as httphandler for Asp.net Mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, captcha, httphandler

I need StackExchange style human verification mechanism.

If client makes more than y requests per x seconds than 1) store "the request", 2) show human verification.

If client passes human verfication call  "stored request".

But it must be global not page spesific. So I guess I need httphandler for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create an [action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209.aspx) in which you identify user by cookie(or ip. both are not perfect), log request for user, retrieve request statistics for user, act accordingly.

this is very similar to AuthorizeAttribute